# React unit test - fireEvent says DOM element doesn't exist when querySelector says it does

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to write a test for my React app as so

```
it('launches dialog and can close dialog with close button', async () => {
  const wrapper = mountComponent();

  // Click to open the dialog
  fireEvent.click(wrapper.container.querySelector('[rel="file-as-nil-button"]'));

  // The Dialog is open
  const filAsNilDialog = wrapper.container.querySelector('[data-ref="file-as-nil-dialog"]');
  expect(filAsNilDialog).toBeTruthy();

  // The close button exists
  const closeButton = wrapper.container.querySelector('[data-ref="cancel"]');
  fireEvent.click(wrapper.container.querySelector('[data-ref="cancel"]'));
});
```

I want to test that I can open a modal / dialog window and then that the user can close the dialog window

The issue I'm having is with the final line fireEvent closing the window - I am retrieving this error message

```
Error: Unable to fire a "click" event - please provide a DOM element.
```

But the line above checks that the closeButton exists - if I comment out the final line of code fireEvent the test passes so I know that the DOM element exists

I think I must have a misunderstand of what is happening here

Comment: How do you know `closeButton` isn't `undefined`?

Comment: I can add 'expect(closeButton).toBeTruthy();' and the test will pass .. or changing the value closeButton to say closeButtonTest will then fail the test

Comment: Neil, could you please use `wrapper.debug(closeButton)` to see if it is really a DOM element?  `.toBeTruthy` accepts a lot of things that aren't a DOM element, as `fireEvent.click` is complaining.

Comment: Console log gives me - <button
        class="secondary"
        data-ref="cancel"
      >
        Cancel
      </button>